# Online accounts-Facebook account showing in hindi language

Tags: language-support, online-accounts

I've just installed Ubuntu trusty tahr (14.04) and while configuring facebook account in Empathy, the labels are showing in hindi language but not in English. How to change this to English.[image]

Comment: better check FB home page. and change language to ENG(US)

Answer (score 1):

Your language setting seems to have become inconsistent somehow. To fix it, go to *System Settings -> Language Support*, change the language to something else, and then change it back to English. Next time you log in your system ought to be completely in English.